# Wordpress buddypress 2.6.1.1 activation email message amend

Tags: wordpress, email, buddypress, activation

I am trying to change the user activation email message in the above.
Searched and read lots of links which dont seem to be relevant to the new version.

The issue I have, is for some users, the activation link doesnt work correctly, and they are asked to input their activation key on the page they are directed to.

My fix at the moment (if i can get it working, ill change the fix to hook into the relevant action instead) involvs changing the 'bp-core-functions.php' file, modifying the messages to include a reference to the actual key, that the user can copy and paste if need be.

```
 'core-user-registration' => array(
        /* translators: do not remove {} brackets or translate its contents. */
        'post_title'   => __( '[{{{site.name}}}] Activate your account', 'buddypress' ),
        /* translators: do not remove {} brackets or translate its contents. */
        'post_content' => __( "Thanks for registering!\n\nTo complete the activation of your account, go to the following link: <a href=\"{{{activate.url}}}\">{{{activate.url}}}</a>. Or enter the following key if prompted: {{{key}}}", 'buddypress' ),
        /* translators: do not remove {} brackets or translate its contents. */
        'post_excerpt' => __( "Thanks for registering!\n\nTo complete the activation of your account, go to the following link: {{{activate.url}}}.  Or enter the following key if prompted: {{{key}}}", 'buddypress' ),
    ),
```

Ive also changed the same messages in the .pot file....just because the messages are also located within their...just to try to get this change to kick in.

Its not working. Anyone have any idea how i can change the activation related message that is sent to users?

thanks
Shaun

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
    //  Get the slug of the activation page
    $slug = $bp->pages->{"activate"}->slug;

    //  Get username from the signup form just posted
    $username = $bp->signup->username;

    //  SQL query to get activation key for that username
    $sql = 'select meta_value from wp_usermeta where meta_key="activation_key" and user_id in (select ID from wp_users where user_login="' . $username . '" and user_status=2)';

    //  Getting the activation key from the database
    $activation_key = $wpdb->get_var($sql);



    //  Custom message with activation key
    $message = "Yayy! Thanks for signing up! Please confirm your account!\n\n$activation_key";

    return $message;
}
?>
```

Paste it in bp-custom.php in plugin folder

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply...youve only given some of the page code...could you be more specific?  eg...which method is this code at the bottom of, ...ill look into the use of a bp-custom file, thanks.

Comment: I had same issue. I uninstalled Yoast seo and every thing start working again. There is buddypress fillter add_filter('bp_core_signup_send_validation_email_message', 'custom_bp_change_activation_email_message');function custom_bp_change_activation_email_message($message) {
 // Get some globals
 global $bp, $wpdb;